# Should I only store IDs into Redis and then query SQL using the IDs

Tags: c#, redis

If I want to display the recent X amount of recent posts\comments on the page, I store a list of IDs using `LPUSH` and then use `LTRIM` to keep the list a certain size.

Do I then use the IDs returned from `LRANGE` to get the details of the post\comments from:

a) Redis using `MGET` where I pass:

MGET comment.1.author, comment.1.content, comment.1.timestamp, comment.2.author, etc

Is it OK to store all the comments details in Redis like that?

b) SQL Database using the list if IDs in a query

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to store the fields individually like that, a *hash* would seem more appropriate than 5 keys each, i.e. where "comment.1" is the key, with subkeys "author", "content", etc. However, unless you have a *reason* to just want the IDs, I would be tempted to store the entire thing as a serialized chunk of json or binary - then you just `LRANGE` and you *have the data* - no fuss, and minimal trips.

To reduce bandwidth, I'd use something like protobuf-net for the storage (although I may be biased), and if you need a binary safe client BookSleeve will do quite nicely.

Comment: Marc, what about deep paging performance costs? Is the overhead negligible? Moreover, if we let the users choose the number of items to show per page we will end up caching the same items quite a few times, no? Thanks in advance

Comment: @CarlosMendes I don't quite follow the question - can you rephrase?

Comment: @MarcGravell, using SO as an example, users can choose the number of questions they want to see per page (15, 30 or 50). I was assuming that storing just the IDs in a list could be a good idea since we could get the 'X' IDs (15, 30 or 50) corresponding to the questions for a specific page and then fetch the data. Regarding deep paging, since a LRANGE operation in a Redis List is a "O(S+N) S is the start offset and N is the number of elements" I was wondering if the performance cost of paging data through a REDIS list with LRANGE wouldn't be high for the higher pages (eg: show page 1500)

Comment: @Carlos ah, right. Yes, it is indeed O(S+N) for [S]tart and [N]umber, but still insanely fast